# Binary Operator '-' cannot be applied to two '[Float]' operands - Surge.framework

Tags: swift

I recently checked out a fresh copy of the Surge framework [here](https://github.com/mattt/Surge). I successfully added it into our Xcode project however I am receiving the following compile-error.

`Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two '[Float]' operands`

I then tried importing it into a fresh clean XCode project and I still get the same error. Has anyone seen this error before and knows a fix? Or is it an issue with the framework itself.

Comment: Apparently, that was an oversight in a [recent commit](https://github.com/mattt/Surge/commit/f40b3c6a9941dfbc18f4f3bbcdd8a808b0d17286) to the Surge library which you [fixed already](https://github.com/rprechelt/Surge/commit/5f1e87f3ebb7f5df134d055a95a589bd1c18e709).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Turns out that this was an oversight with the latest commit to the framework, and wasn't me missing something obvious.

Comment: If your problem is solved do not forget to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can not us binary operator on arrays, which is what you have. You can tell because "Float" is surrounded by brackets. You can only use binary operators on individual values.

```
var myArray = [Float]()  //An array(note the brackets)

myArray.append(15)   //myArray now contains one value(15), but you still can't use binary operators on it because its an array.
print(myArray + myArray) //Error
print(myArray[0] + myArray[0]) //prints 30,  using this syntax "myArray[0]" represents the first object in the array, 30 in this case.
```

Long story short, switch to a non array float if you don't need an array, or directly access the items you want in your array in order to use binary operator on them.

Comment: Thanks for the help; but this wasn't exactly my question. I am aware that you can't traditionally use binary operators on arrays however the Surge framework overloads the binary operators for [Float]'s and [Double] using the Accelerate framework. Considering that this library is well-developed (see the link in my post), I'm concerned that some element of my XCode configuration is causing this error (because '+', '-', '*' and '/' all work on arrays)